# Spring-ws XML bomb protection, anyone?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, spring-ws

Is there a way to protect Spring-WS app from XML bombs, if I am using JAXB2 un/marshaler...and Xalan 2.7.1 and Xerces, though I no longer know who depends on what anymore :) ....

Basically I want to disable DTD as schema language in entire app, and if that could be done from app context xml file, that would be great!

I guess the other option would be to extend/implement some class/interface, and change some method, but I don't know where in Spring-WS is parser first called....

Answer (score 3):

Java parsers generally have built-in protected for things like entity expansion attacks:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
XMLReader xmlReader = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileReader("input.xml"));
SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/preventing-entity-expansion-attacks-in.html